# c++ constructor 'ambiguous' -- but it's actually not

Tags: c++, c++11

First you need to see the code below --

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl ;

class test
{
    private:
        int data1, data2 ;
    public:
        test(int data1 = 1) { 
            this->data1 = data1 ; this->data2 = -1;
        }
        test(int data1 = 1, int data2 = 2) { 
            this->data1 = data1 ; this->data2 = data2 ; 
        }
};
```

and this is the main --

```
int main()
{
    test t1(1) ;
    test t2(1, 2);
    return 1 ;
}
```

Here you can see I am using two types of default constructor with different initializer, but when I try to compile, the compiler says the that the constructor arguments are 'ambiguous'. Moreover, the end of the compiler message says something about `constexpr` -- which I have no idea what this is all about.

what I am missing ?

and here is the compiler error message --

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:19:11: error: call of overloaded ‘test(int)’ is ambiguous
  test t1(1) ;
           ^
test.cpp:19:11: note: candidates are:
test.cpp:12:3: note: test::test(int, int)
   test(int data1 = 1, int data2 = 2) { 
   ^
test.cpp:9:3: note: test::test(int)
   test(int data1 = 1) { 
   ^
test.cpp:4:7: note: constexpr test::test(const test&)
 class test
       ^
test.cpp:4:7: note: constexpr test::test(test&&)
```

Comment: Why do you think they are not ambiguous?

Comment: `I am using two types of default constructor with different initializer` and there lies the problem.

Comment: side note: `return 1 ;` -> `return 0 ;` or don't put `return` in main at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first overload takes 0-1 argument; the second takes 0-2 arguments. So, when called with either 0 or 1 arguments, both are equally good. Therefore, it's ambiguous.

The fact that, as you say, these are "two types of default constructor" pretty much *guarantees* that they're ambiguous. If you create two default constructors, how can the compiler know which one to use?

Answer (score 3):

The compiler has every right to give you the error because this `test(int data1 = 1, int data2 = 2)` means that if there was **no** other function overload like `test(int data1 = 1)` then i should still be able to call  `test(int data1 = 1, int data2 = 2)` like this

```
test(2);
```

So it is definitely ambiguous. What you are facing is *[most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse#Example_with_functions)*.
The "most vexing parse" is a term coined by Scott Meyers for an ambiguity in C++ declaration syntax that leads to counter-intuitive behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Is *is* ambiguous:  You can call

```
test(int data1 = 1) { 
    this->data1 = data1 ; this->data2 = -1;
}
```

with 0 or 1 parameters, and

```
test(int data1 = 1, int data2 = 2) { 
    this->data1 = data1 ; this->data2 = data2 ; 
}
```

with 0, 1, or 2.
-> What should the compiler do with 0 or 1?

Answer (score 0):

if you call test(), which of the two constructors will be called?? the problem is that the arguments of the cunstructors have a default value, if you remove the default value i'm pretty sure it will work, because you have to specify the input arguments which uniquely determines the correct constructor

Answer (score 0):

In this definition of object `t1`

```
test t1(1) ;
```

there can be called either the first constructor declared like

```
test(int data1 = 1);
```

with argument 1 or the second constructor declared like

```
    test(int data1 = 1, int data2 = 2);
```

with the first argument equal to 1 and the second argument that is the default argument.

To escape the ambiguity you could declare the second constructor like

```
    test(int data1, int data2 );
```

Take into account that there is a contradiction between your original constructors. If the first constructor is used then data member data2 has default value -1 while if the second constructor is used then the default value of data member data2 is 2. It is a bad design because it can obly confuse users.L)